# Cannot install QTNX on Ubuntu 13

Tags: nx, freenx

A freenx server is running on the machine but I cannot install QTNX

```
root@al2:~/Downloads# sudo apt-get install qtnx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package qtnx is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'qtnx' has no installation candidate
root@al2:~/Downloads#
```

Any help appreciated.

------------------- EDITED

I went with http://nomachine.org.
I could not have the quantal install work quickly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks as if the qtnx client was deleted from the ubutu repositories as of 13.04

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/amd64/qtnx/0.9-3ubuntu4

You can try the quantal build https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtnx/ or build from source.